# Can I figure out whether there is a miss correspondence between my loss function and accuracy?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network, loss-function, pytorch-lightning

I think my loss does not match the accuracy

Training accuracy of 0.037.

Training loss of 0.35.

I am using CrossEntropyLoss and multiclassAccuracy with 397 classes

This is my model

```
class ResNetLightningModule(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, num_labels=397, lr=1.0e-03):
        super().__init__()

        self.save_hyperparameters()

        self.loss_function = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

        self.model = ResNetForImageClassification.from_pretrained("microsoft/resnet-50")
        self.model.classifier = nn.Sequential(nn.Dropout(0.5), nn.Flatten(start_dim=1, end_dim=-1), nn.Linear(2048, num_labels))

        self.accuracy_top_1 = MulticlassAccuracy(num_classes=self.hparams.num_labels, top_k=1)
        self.accuracy_top_5 = MulticlassAccuracy(num_classes=self.hparams.num_labels, top_k=5)

    def forward(self, X):
        logits = self.model(X).logits
        return logits

    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        X, y = batch
        logits = self(X)

        loss = self.loss_function(logits, y)
        self.log("train_loss", loss, on_epoch=True)

        acc1 = self.accuracy_top_1(logits, y)
        self.log("train_accuracy_1", acc1, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True)
        return loss
```

Comment: Neither accuracy or loss are computed on logits, which is what your code is doing.

Comment: Inputs to ```nn.CrossEntropyLoss``` can be unnormalized logits. However I am not sure about the ```MulticlassAccuracy``` you are using. I dont think this particular function is in torchmetrics. However make sure if the metric function you are using accepts unnormalized logits. You can also check out torchmetrics (https://torchmetrics.readthedocs.io/en/stable/classification/accuracy.html). This accepts unnormalized logits as its input.